# Problema com o reconhecimento do arquivo.h

Tags: c++

Bom criei um `arquivo.h` e um `arquivo.cpp`, do `arquivo.cpp` ao incluir o `#include "arquivo.h"` reconhece automaticamente, já no meu main.cpp não reconhece ai não consigo utilizar o dado desse arquivo.

Comment: Não entendi o que você, é melhor postar os códigos ou explicar melhor o problema. O que significa "não reconhece"?

Comment: por causa deste erro aqui `undefined reference o 'inicializa()'.`, vale lembra que o arquivos estão na mesma pasta, era para funcionar.

Comment: Está com cara de ser problema na hora de *linkar*, o erro deve estar na linha de comando. È só um chute devido a falta de informações.

Comment: Você incluiu o arquivo.h no main.cpp?

Comment: sim, pois quando falo que não reconhece é o fato de você apertar `Ctrl + espaço  ` .

Comment: Você ja tentou clicar em Rescan Solution no menu Project?

Comment: Onde fica essa opção estou utilizando o code blocks

Comment: @Rodolfo ah, essa opção é no visual studio

Comment: Valeu pessoal achei meu erro.

Answer (score -1):

Bom descobri meu erro

as opções debug e release estava desmarcados.

Para verificar bastas ir no aba do arquivo que você criou clicar com o direito e selecionar as caixas

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]